# C string literal vs. C string array/pointer with P/Invoke not working correctly

Tags: c#, c, interop, pinvoke, mingw

I have this simple situation setup:

Basic .NET Code:

```
[DllImport ... stuff... use cdecl]
public static extern void SetCallback(CallbackDelegate c);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer ... use cdecl]
public delegate CallbackDelegate(MarshalAs(single byte string with null terminating character pointer) string c)    

public static CallbackDelegate theNotGCdDelegate = null;
public void Start() {
    theNotGCdDelegate = new CallbackDelegate(CallbackCalledHere);
    SetCallback(theNotGCdDelegate);
}

public void CallbackCalledHere(string text) {
    Debug.WriteLine(text);
}
```

The Basic C Code (compiled with MinGW):

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl SetCallback(void (__cdecl *TheCallback)(char* text)){
    // This does not work as expected:
    TheCallback("This is a string literal");

    // This works as expected:
    char pointerMessage[] = "This is also a string literal, but referenced by an array.";
    TheCallback(pointerMessage);
}
```

So my situation (and I promise I'm not making this up!), is that calling SetCallback from C with the string literal direct (i.e., TheCallback("Hello World")) results in an empty string (the first byte of the string is NULL).  .NET converts this to an empty string (i.e., "").  I've confirmed that this is the case by using Marshal.ReadByte and by Marshaling the parameter as an IntPtr myself.

In the second case (when declaring a pointer/array and passing that variable into TheCallback), I get the string perfectly and as expected!

That doesn't make sense to me theoretically.  Both strings should be placed in the data section of the C DLL and both have pointers which should never move!  Both situations should pass pointers to actual data.  I have no warnings on my compile.

This may be related, but maybe not:
I'm running on a 64 bit machine.  I am 100% certain that when I compile a 32 bit DLL in MinGW, that I always call that DLL from a 32 bit process space in my .NET application (explicitly outputting a 32 bit assembly).  Likewise, when I compile the 64 bit DLL, I always call that DLL from 64 bit process space in my .NET application (explicitly outputting a 64 bit assembly).

I've verified that the proper 32 bit flag is showing up in Task Manager and is missing on the 64 bit build.  The DLL is only located in the bin directory and is not regsvr32'd.

**Importantly, the 64bit DLL doesn't exhibit this problem: both strings are passed through correctly to the .NET runtime.  The 32bit DLL exhibits the problem which I've stated above.**

I'm compiling/linking the 32bit DLL with the gcc/ld from MinGW (from http://mingw.org/).  I'm compiling/linking the 64bit DLL with the mingw-w64-bin_i686-mingw_20111220.zip package from http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/

Can anyone explain what is happening here?  Or maybe you'd rather recommend a different compiler or compiler flags?

**EDIT**

I just found out that GetFunctionPointerForDelegate works only with stdcall functions.  I think thats an important point.  I was using this Marshal call on and off, but I guess I'll completely avoid it now since the callback should be cdecl.  I'm assuming the UnmanagedFunctionPointer notation should be sufficient to pass a pointer to a cdecl function.

Comment: In your second code block: shouldn't `SetCallback` read `TheCallback`, otherwise this would look quiet confusing ... ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that was definitely a problem :)

Comment: The code snippet's quality is extremely poor.  What is the point of not posting the real declarations?  Don't make this up when you type the question, copy and paste.

Comment: Thank you for the criticism, Hans.  I'll copy and paste the exact code later today.  Was there something missing from the pseudo code that was confusing to you?

Comment: What's missing is the actual code. Post real code rather than made up non-compiling explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite missing my 'actual code', this problem was solved by not using ld when compiling.  Apparently I was missing some linker flags which--when using gcc--were automagically added by the compiler.  All my problems went away when I switched to using gcc alone.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: +1, but shouldn't this be community wiki now that you've answered it yourself?

Comment: Any idea which flags were significant?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea what flags gcc added that I didn't have in ld.  From the poking around I did, I'm guessing that there might have been some issue with the base load address of the DLL not being set (or something similar).  Occasionally, the readonly data section of the DLL wasn't being relocated to the right place in memory--that's what set me on track to look at the linker.  Symptoms were inconsistent AccessViolationExceptions thrown by .NET and inconsistent results between code executions.  The decompilation of the DLL with IDA looked more or less correct.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, gcc normally puts string literals in a read-only section (.rodata for ELF format; not sure what the equivalent would be for Windows).

Try compiling with the -fwritable-strings option and see if that makes a difference.

*Edit*

Double-checked on my Linux system (don't have Mingw handy).  Without the -fwritable-strings option, string literals go in the .rodata section.  With the option, they go in .data.

Comment: So shouldn't I still be able to read data from the read only data section from .NET?  I'll try out what you're suggesting however!  It also doesn't make sense to me why the 64bit compiler doesn't seem to have the same problem as the 32bit version.